# How to login newly to a installed linode (with a stackscript)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, linode

I just got started with linode and ran [this stackscript](http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/view/?StackScriptID=4531)
I tried to ssh in with the username and password I specified to no avail, I can still only ssh with root.
Any ideas?

This is my environment: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
This is my stackscript: 'Rails Enviroments with RVM, Nginx and Passenger' StackScript at revision 21741

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user you specified may not have permissions to ssh into that box.

Try:

```
ssh -v your_user@your_host.com
```

And see if that helps you understand what may be happening.

Comment: thanks. it turns out that it was taking a while to install. i logged in today and it worked. rvm is installed, but i can't find nginx anywhere... help?